# Omitting a value from an object in javascript if it's an empty string

Tags: javascript

```
function a (METRIC,DIMENTIONS){
  var args = {
     'ids': ids,
     'start-date': START_DATE,
     'end-date': END_DATE,
     'metrics': METRIC,
     'dimensions': DIMENTIONS
  };
}
```

I have this array in javascript where `dimensions` is an optional value 
i want to check if `DIMENTIONS` is an empty string i want my args to look like this :

```
var args = {
     'ids': ids,
     'start-date': START_DATE,
     'end-date': END_DATE,
     'metrics': METRIC
  };
```

i tried this :

```
var args = {
     'ids': ids,
     'start-date': START_DATE,
     'end-date': END_DATE,
     'metrics': METRIC,
    DIMENTIONS!=''? 'dimensions': DIMENTIONS : ''
  };
```

but this will keep the `,` after `METRIC` and will produce an error

Comment: why dont to move it out of  object literal?

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: i said it in my post man

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a property from a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate. He does not want to include dimension if DIMENTIONS are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( !args.dimensions )
 delete args.dimensions;
```

That's about it :)

Comment: but how did we check if DIMENTION is null ?

Comment: You said you wanted to check if it is an empty string, this code makes that check

Comment: You include it and then delete it. That is not optimal

Comment: I don't, OP does :) You're right they shouldn't be doing that. Guess i focused on the question title mostly

Answer (score 1):

naive and simple solutuion:

```js
function a (METRIC,DIMENTIONS){
  var args = {
     'ids': ids,
     'start-date': START_DATE,
     'end-date': END_DATE,
     'metrics': METRIC
  };
  
  if(DIMENTIONS) {
  args['dimensions']   = DIMENTIONS;
  }
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 11 secs - you may want to have dimentions if they are 0

Answer (score 1):

> Do not add this key in object initially. Check if is a valid value then add it!

```
var args = {
  'ids': ids,
  'start-date': START_DATE,
  'end-date': END_DATE,
  'metrics': METRIC
};
if (typeOf DIMENTIONS !== 'undefined') {
  args.dimensions = DIMENTIONS;
}
```